# Strip down a gedcom file

Tags: gedcom, family-tree-maker

I have a big Gedcom file which I‘d like to reduce on:
Name, birth, marriage, death.

Best would be if I could do it the other way around like exporting the data from FTM to a gedcom and add the columns I like to have in my gedcom file.

How do I do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! You can use the edit link under your question to add data at any time. Are you trying to get a stripped-down GEDCOM file for a specific purpose (e.g. attaching it to a DNA kit)? When you say "birth, marriage, death" do you want to include both dates and places?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explain your problem a little better as I am not sure I understand what you want to do.

Assuming that you have multiple facts against each individual in your file and you want to reduce these down and then create a new Gedcom from that then these are a couple of possible options.

1: Use a programme such as [Family Historian](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/) which allows the creation of queries on your data and set the query with the facts that you want and then export that result set to a new Gedcom.

2: Use something like [GedXLate](http://www.gedmagic.com/gedxlate.htm) (very old but still works fine) to export minimal data from your Gedcom in to Excel format. Edit the file in Excel and then use one of the many Excel to Gedcom converters to make the edited file a new Gedcom.

If you want something different come back with a better explanation of your problem.

Comment: tried gedXlate... from different sources :-( Download doesn*t work or is a corrupt file. Other recommendations?

Comment: gedXlate still downloads and installs fine for me. I have put it on my Google drive try downloading from there. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HEX7PYi9bemn4V28N7WBqbjdSewhpCHP Let me know once you have it and I will delete it. I zipped it up so you will need to unzip.